# How does clang detect noexcept-ness?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

I'm currently reimplementing `std::invoke` in C++11 (i.e. understanding and adapting libc++/libstdc++ code), and I stumbled upon an issue related to `noexcept`.

This can be demonstrated with the following snippet:

```
#include <functional>

void nothrow_method(int, int) noexcept
{
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  static_assert(noexcept(std::__invoke(nothrow_method, 2, 3)), "");
  static_assert(std::__is_nothrow_invocable<decltype(nothrow_method), int, int>::value, "");
}
```

I'm on Debian Jessie, my library is libstdc++.

Compiling with `-std=c++14` fails with clang 4.0.1, both `static_assert` trigger.
There is no problem with GCC 7.1.0 however.

I looked at how libc++ implemented `std::invoke`, and I copied their way of detecting `noexcept` in my own implementation, but it still failed to compile.

Since there is only one error line because of the `static_assert`, I really have no idea what is going on, could it be related to what's explained in this [blog post](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/)?

I've had some issues with `noexcept` and template instantiation points in the past, but I'm quite sure it's not related here.

**EDIT:**

I've downloaded libcxx trunk, built with apple-clang 8.1.0 on macOS 10.12.6, the `static_assert` still trigger, despite their code having `noexcept(noexcept())` on `__invoke`.

**EDIT2:**

`std::__*` are used for tests, I know they are private, but I didn't want to post my `invoke` implementation.

Comment: From the article you linked: `Note: clang currently has a bug where noexcept does not yield true even though the expression checked is a constant-expression. A workaround is available in the appendix of this post.`

Comment: Before C++17 `noexcept` is not part of the function type, so `void nothrow_method(int, int) noexcept;` and `void throwing_method(int, int);` have the same type.

Comment: @tkausl I don't see how it could be linked to that issue, since I'm not dealing with constant expressions.

Comment: @cpplearner Indeed, but I've seen `__invoke` being used internally by both libc++ and libstdc++ since C++03 (for the former at least). I checked again and there is a macro `_LIBCXX_INVOKE_RETURN` that handles the `noexcept(noexcept(...))` clause, the trailing return type, and the call in itself. I've seen `noexcept` tests in the libcxx test suite with `invoke`, I'm sure their implementation is correct... I will try to compile with clang on macOS and post my results.

Comment: Aren't std::__*   private to the implementation of the stl, and std::invoke() and std::is_no_throw_invokable c++17 features?  Calling metafunctions outside of the standard is bordering on UB, This can not help understanding....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the Clang standard library, probably in the definitions of std::invoke<> and std::__is_nothrow_invocable<>... GCC correctly doesn't assert on both statements, and VS2017 does exhibit the bug.

As an aside, you should avoid the std::__*<> templates — they are not part of the standard and are meant to be private to the standard library.

Here's a workaround: you can use the following syntax, which is more correct, since it tests the actual statement you will use in the app.

```
#include <functional>

void nothrow_method(int, int) noexcept { }

int main()
{
    static_assert(noexcept(nothrow_method(2, 3)), "");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know one should never do that, that's just for testing purposes, since I am reimplementing `invoke` as I mentioned at the top of my post (I should have insisted on that sorry for the confusion). So the point that is of interest to me here is specifically `invoke`'s noexcept-ness. I'm currently building the latests clang/libcxx to see if it's fixed, it might be because of a compiler internal trait that this works on GCC.

Comment: I've checked vs2017's invoke, since it also fails the static_assert.  It does have a noexcept clause, which is odd.  Correction:  `std::invoke` does _not_ have a noexcept clause.

Comment: Thanks for checking on VS! I had no success with latest libc++/clang... I'm leaning towards a compiler internal that is making GCC works.